# PHP script to send notification email via hosted ISP

Tags: php, email

I have PHP 5 running on a hosted ISP.  The ISP gives me minimal configuration options via cPanel.  Is there any way to use email notification to respond to some given event?  I want to send from PHP in the background.  Must I specify environment stuff like POP or SMTP?  My hosted ISP offers email addresses of course -- does using one of those make things easier?  Now that you know how ignorant I am, do you have any general advice on approaching this?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific and tell us what "given event" you'd like to receive a notification about? It's hard to answer your question without understanding what you're trying to monitor.

Comment: Merely based on what code is invoked in the PHP files.  For example, a specified query against the MySQL data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hosting company may have set up the environment already for you. Have a look at the [PHP mail page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and write a test script to send yourself an email.